# Separación de palabras en python

Tags: python, inteligencia-artificial, nlp

Tengo una gran duda. ¿Existe algo en python capaz de identificar los verbos, adjetivos, etc. de un texto? ¿O tendría que hacerlo manualmente con condiciones?

Comment: Sí, son herramientas para "Lenguaje Natural" que, en general, equivale a procesar texto en inglés. Mira [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/).

Comment: Increible! Gracias por la ayuda, sirvio bastante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si.. exactamente la tenica se basa en lenguaje natural o NLP en sus siglas en ingles. Si lo vas hacer en python, te recomiendo que trabajes con la libreria NLTK con el corpus de español.

Te recomiendo la siguiente discusion, seguramente vas a tener una mejor idea de lo que buscas hacer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732465/nltk-tagging-spanish-words-using-a-corpus

Adicionalmente de recomiendo las APIs de la empresa molino de ideas. He trabajado cn algunas parq calificador de sentimiento en python y tienen muy buenos resultados. Te dejo el link de la API de busca de verbo:

http://store.apicultur.com/apis/info?name=BuscaVerbo&version=1.0.0&provider=MolinodeIdeas

Answer (score 0):

Existe una librería para `python 2.7` llamada [pattern](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/pattern-en). Que trabaja con diversos idiomas dentro de ellos el español, para conocer que etiqueta tiene una palabra pattern ofrece una serie de opciones, un ejemplo según la documentación es la siguiente:

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   import pattern.es as lemEsp
   print lemEsp.parse('estan', lemmata=True)
```

Donde la salida seria algo como esto:

```
   'están/VB/B-VP/O/estar'
```

Finalmente, cada `'/'` es un separador que muestra cierta información a cerca de la palabra en cuestión, en el segundo separador indica que tipo de palabra es, y según este [enlace](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/MBSP-tags) indican que para esa etiqueta, la palabra corresponde es un verbo.